# Text to columns: How to prevent date formatting of decimal numers?

Tags: excel

With a dataset such as this:

```
Date, Value
04.03.2020, 13.35
04.03.2020, 13.8
04.03.2020, 21.21
```

You can split the data using `Data > Text to columns` and specifying the value separator.

The problem is that Excel recognizes `13.8` as `august 13`, so the output is:

```
Date    Value
04.03.2020  13.35
04.03.2020  13.aug
04.03.2020  21.21
```

How can I make sure that Excel *never* interprets decimal numbers such as `13.8` as dates?

I'm working in a region that uses `,` as decimal separator, but I often have to work with data that is set up with `.` as the decimal separator. One work-around is of course to replace `,` with `;` and `.` with `,` before opening a `.csv` file. And if the only other solution is to set it up with VBA, I'm perfectly able to do so myself. But I often find myself trying to help colleagues on their computers without my own `VBA` configurations ready to go. So if there's any other way to do this using standard Excel system settings, that would be great!

This little problem has bugged me for years and I'm eager to get rid of it once and for all.

**Edit:**

I'm running Excel version 1908 on Windows 7, Office 365.

This problem often occurs when I'd like to inspect csv files that are recognized as Excel files on my system. There have been suggestions to format the cells as `General` before splitting the data. That does not seem to work on my end.

Comment: One hack-ish way to do this would be changing date and time settings in windows options (I'm assuming you're using windows)... do you think that would be acceptable for your colleagues?

Comment: @vestland did you check the formatting of `Value` column? Set `Value` column format to `General` and try again. i have test the data provided and i receive what exactly you want without any conversion to dates

Comment: @Francesco Thank you for your suggestion, but that seems to mess up  whole other bunch of stuff since all other files are set up with comma as the decimal separator.

Comment: @Error1004 Perhaps because we've got different date and time settings? And different decimal separator?

Comment: I asked because I usually use the forward slash `/` as date separator, and this problem would not apply to me. But I'm not judging any way of formatting a spreadsheet! Unfortunately it seems an unavoidable behaviour from excel, also formatting the cells as text doesn't solve this. Can you control how the cvs is created?

Comment: @Francesco I see! Yes, I can control how most of our csv files are created. If not, then I can reformat them before loading them. But I was just eager to see it there was another way around this using Excel system settings.

Comment: @vestland maybe your write. i have propose a solution to overcome this issue.

Comment: @Error1004 Cool! I really appreciate your efforts.

Comment: @vestland during `Text to Column` process at `Step 3` you have the option to to select `Data Column Format` you could also select the `Value` column and play around with `Text` or `General` formating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution is to get what you want with formulas:

**Formula for Dates:**

`=TEXT(LEFT(A2,FIND(",",A2,1)-1),"General")`

**Formula for Values:**

`=TEXT(MID(A2,(FIND(",",A2,1)+2),(LEN(A2)-(FIND(",",A2,1)+1))),"General")`

**Results:**

[image]

During Text to Column process at Step 3 you have the option to to select Data Column Format you could also select the Value column and play around with Text or General formating.

[image]

Comment: How very cool and *extremely* embarrasing at the same time. I'm blind! I don't work much with Excel anymore. At the time that Excel was my go-to data tool, I had VBA shortcuts that took care of this for me; reading text files, replacing values, taking care of the date formatting and so on. At some point in time, this feature must have been added without me noticing. Thank you!

Comment: After some fooling around, I found that the best approach was to click `Advanced` in your image above and specify the decimal sepator as `.`. Thanks again!